# Consistency of theories

Tags: logic

1) Can we express the consistency of a theory $T$ by the formula
$\sim\exists x\  (\sim x=x)$? i.e, there is no $x$ such that $x$ does not equal $x$.

2) If so, can we that say that if $T$ is consistent with a sufficient amount of arithmetic,then there is no proof in $T$ of this formula? That is $T$ does not prove 'For all $x$, $x = x$'?

Comment: As to 1), the assertion is a theorem. It does not appear to have a connection with consistency.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what @AndréNicolas is saying is that $\sim\exists x\ (\sim x=x)$ can be proved both in consistent theories and in incosistent theories. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: A typesetting oddity: In $a\sim b$, the space before and after "$\sim$" is what is suitable for binary operators, as in $5+3$, but if one writes $+3$, so that "$+$" is a unary operator, there's not as much space between the plus sign and the digit, whereas in $\sim x=x$ one still gets standard binary-operator spacing.  I tried coding it as {\sim}x rather than \sim x, but then it seems as if there's too little space: ${\sim}x= x$. Whoever wrote the code didn't contemplate the possibility of "$\sim$" as a unary operator.  When one mods out by "$\sim$", $\text{writing }\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: ${}\ldots\,A/{\sim}$, coded as A/{\sim}, then the curly braces do succeed in eliminating the extra space that's not right for the context.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Every first-order theory proves $\forall x(x=x)$; depending how you set it up, this is either one of the axioms of first-order logic, or is easily deducible from those axioms together with the inference rules.

To express consistency, you want to say: $$T\mbox{ does not prove } \exists x(x\not=x).$$ But this is not the same as the bare sentence $$\forall x(x\not=x),$$ which is just a true statement (and doesn't mention $T$ at all); and it is also not the same as $$T\mbox{ does prove }\forall x(x\not=x),$$ which all $T$ will do.

Indeed, on the face of it the sentence "$T$ does not prove $\exists x(x\not=x)$" isn't expressible at all in (the language of arithmetic in) a first-order manner; figuring out how to do this was part of Goedel's great achievement.

Comment: Mmmm... reflexive theories...

Comment: Can we reason: T proves ~x=x --> ~x=x. Also ~x=x--> anything .so 'T proves ~x=x 'is equivalent to ~x=x?